sqlite3 script using cksumvfs extension
I need of a script performing a quick integrity check on a sqlite database.
I've tried using cksumvfs sqlite extension and, performing on the sqlite3 shell, all seems ok.
Using the same sequence on a simple bash script the results is "ok" also on corrupted databases.
The script is like this:
    /usr/bin/sqlite3 /xxx/mydb_corrupted.sqlite <<EOF
    .load /yyy/cksumvfs
    .open /xxx/mydb_corrupted.sqlite;
    .vfsinfo
    PRAGMA quick_check;
    EOF


I've added the command ".vsfsinfo" to be sure that the extension has been loaded.
The output is:
    vfs.zName      = "cksmvfs"
    vfs.iVersion   = 3
    vfs.szOsFile   = 152
    vfs.mxPathname = 1024
    ok

The output of the same commands on a sqlite3 shell give a correct response:
    sqlite> .load /yyy/cksumvfs
    sqlite> .open  /xxx/mydb_corrupted.sqlite
    sqlite> .vfsinfo
    vfs.zName      = "cksmvfs"
    vfs.iVersion   = 3
    vfs.szOsFile   = 152
    vfs.mxPathname = 1024
    sqlite> PRAGMA quick_check;
    *** in database main ***
    On tree page 27819 cell 0: invalid page number 27947
     [... cut ...]
    Error: database disk image is malformed
    sqlite> 


